# Eclipse Kepler crashing frequently

Tags: eclipse

I am using eclipse kepler to develop a dynamic web project running on apache tomcat 7.
Everything was working fine initially however since last couple of days eclipse is crashing very frequently almost with in 15-20 minutes of starting it . This is the terminal output. I am using ubuntu 10.10 (maverick).

> zer0cube@zer0cube-G31M:~/eide/eclipse$ ./eclipse
>
> Warning(optionsfile.cc:22): Load: Could not open file
>
> No bp log location saved, using default.
>
> [000:000] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
>
> [000:000] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
>
> [000:000] Using Gtk2 toolkit
>
> [000:004] Warning(optionsfile.cc:22): Load: Could not open file
>
> [000:004] Warning(optionsfile.cc:22): Load: Could not open file
>
> [000:004] No bp log location saved, using default.
>
> [000:004] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
>
> [000:004] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
>
> [000:004] Using Gtk2 toolkit
>
> Segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

You are getting segmentation fault.

A segmentation fault occurs when a program attempts to access a memory location that it is not allowed to access, or attempts to access a memory location in a way that is not allowed (for example, attempting to write to a read-only location, or to overwrite part of the operating system).

Try forcing mozilla, I believe webkit-gtk is causing the segfault.
./eclipse -vmargs -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla